# this object reference not working inside $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why won't foo get appended?

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                url: 'barfoochakalaka',
                success:
                    function(response) {
                        $.each(response, function(index, val) {                             
                            $(this).parent().parent().append('foo');
                        });

                    }
})
```

Comment: What do you want `this` to be?

Comment: because the line before it is getting an error.  Look at the javascript console to see what the error message is.

Comment: within a `$.each()`, `this` refers to the element currently being looped through by the `$.each`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because inside `each`, `this` is set to the current element being iterated over ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)), so normally we define `this` to be something else before we enter the `each` loop:

```
var that = this;
$.each(response, function(index, val) {
    var content = '<div class="link-history">'+ val.date + ', ' + val.userid + ', ' + val.status + '</div>';
    $(that).parent().parent().append('foo');
});
```

However, in **this** circumstance, `this` in the `success` callback of an AJAX request is equal to the `jqXHR` object which launched the request, not the `DOM` element you're after, so we have to move the `var that = this` to even further away;

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    url: 'barfoochakalaka',
    success: function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(index, val) {
            var content = '<div class="link-history">' + val.date + ', ' + val.userid + ', ' + val.status + '</div>';
            $(that).parent().parent().append('foo');
        });

    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var $this = $('#Selector').parent().parent();
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                url: 'barfoochakalaka',
                success:
                    function(response) {
                        $.each(response, function(index, val) {
                            var content = '<div class="link-history">'+ val.date + ', ' + val.userid + ', ' + val.status + '</div>';
                            $this.append('foo');
                        });

                    }
})
```

---

EDIT:

added `.parent().parent()` to the original selector, so you are not calling this for each loop

Answer (score 0):

Response may not be an array, just a string. Try assigning the response to an element and then using a selector to grab all children in that element before doing an .each()

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not an object of elements, it's most likely a list of strings possibly with your selectors(?) if that's it then use `$($(this))`.